# How to open a popup image for completely different image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have two images to use for instance rose.jpg and mary.jpg. I need to pop up mary.jpg once I click to rose.jpg. I am trying to use modal in here. I know how to do it if the pop image is same as the image to be clicked but in this case my bigger image has a completely different name. I have seen multiple other examples which describes about popup window or form but not image in itself while clicking the image.
Following is what I have done so far. It works only for same image:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

.modal {
    display: none; 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); 
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}


.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img id="myImg" src="rose.jpg" alt="flower" >


<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" src="mary.jpg" alt="mary" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example `modalImg.src = this.src;` is what it is getting the original image to pop up instead of the other image. I need to display mary.jpg which I had given source as `<img class="modal-content" src="mary.jpg" alt="mary" id="img01">`. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onclick` function you are setting the img `src` as equal to `this.src`

```
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
```

By doing so, in this use case, every time you click the image you are setting the img src to `rose.jpg`.

If you remove `modalImg.src = this.src;` then your modal should just simply '*open*', by displaying `block` `onclick`, and displaying your HTML, which already defines the img src.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" src="mary.jpg" alt="mary" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```